# How stop running code if event handler return false in yii2

Tags: php, oop, events, yii2, eventhandler

I'm trying to create a module in yii2. I want use events to handle some events in my module and make my module independent to my core.

Now i want stop module code flow if an event throw and even handler of that return false.

Look below code:

```
function withdraw($amount, $description = null)
{
    if (!(is_integer($amount) or is_float($amount) or is_double($amount))) {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException("Amount should be in double.");
    }
    try {
        $event = new TransactionEvent();
        $event->setTransaction($transactionModel);
        $event->setType($event::TYPE_WITHDRAW);
        $this->trigger(\aminkt\userAccounting\UserAccounting::EVENT_WITHDRAW, $event);

        $this->totalWithdraw += $amount;
        if (!$this->save())
            throw new RuntimeException("Purse cant update itself in withdraw action.");

        $transaction->commit();
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        throw $e;
    } catch (\Throwable $e) {
        throw $e;
    }
}
```

This is my now code. I want something below to know event handler work correctly and my transaction saved into database correctly:

```
if($this->trigger(\aminkt\userAccounting\UserAccounting::EVENT_WITHDRAW, event)){
   $this->totalWithdraw += $amount;
   if (!$this->save())
       throw new RuntimeException("Purse cant update itself in withdraw action.");
}else{
   throw new RuntimeException("Transaction handler not worked correctly.");
}
```

Thank you.